# My tailwind scroll snap x is not working, can you please find a solution to this?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

So I use Tailwind CSS, and I ran into a problem. So I am learning how to do scroll snap on tailwind CSS. Scroll snap y works, but scroll snap x does not work. I tried everything to make my code do scroll snap x but it would not work. Can any of you please fix my tailwind code and make it do scroll snap x please? Here is my code:

```css
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Condensed:wght@600&display=swap');
        * {
            font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

    <title>Project Impossible</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="snap-y snap-mandatory h-screen w-screen mx:auto overflow-scroll">
        <div class="snap-start bg-amber-200 grid w-screen h-screen place-items-center  text-8xl">1</div>
        <div class="snap-start bg-blue-200 grid w-screen h-screen place-items-center  text-8xl">2</div>
        <div class="snap-start bg-orange-200 grid w-screen h-screen place-items-center  text-8xl">3</div>
        <div class="snap-start bg-green-200 grid w-screen h-screen place-items-center text-8xl">4</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your demo of y-snap works. Show what you have tried with x-snap.

Comment: [snap x demo link](https://codepen.io/SB-The-Silent-Coder/pen/poLOoag) I tried snap-x as it said in the tailwind website. But it does not work.

Comment: @tauzN Please respond, no one is solving my problem.

Answer (score 6):

You are almost there. The only thing you need to do is to add the `shrink-0` class to your snapping divs:

```css
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Condensed:wght@600&display=swap');
        * {
            font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

    <title>Project Impossible</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex snap-x snap-mandatory h-screen w-full mx:auto overflow-scroll">
        <div class="snap-start     shrink-0    bg-amber-200 grid w-full h-screen place-items-center  text-8xl">1</div>
        <div class="snap-start shrink-0 bg-blue-200 grid w-screen h-screen place-items-center text-8xl">2</div>
        <div class="snap-start shrink-0 bg-orange-200 grid w-screen h-screen place-items-center text-8xl">3</div>
        <div class="snap-start shrink-0 bg-green-200 grid w-screen h-screen place-items-center text-8xl">4</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```